# Php Ajax Html and Javascript usage in code

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

```
<div class="navigation">
<a class="prev" href="index.php?month=__prev_month__" onclick="$('#calendar').load('index.php?month=__prev_month__&_r=' + Math.random()); return false;"></a>
<!-- <div class="title" >__cal_caption__</div> -->
<a class="next" href="index.php?month=__next_month__" onclick="$('#calendar').load('index.php?month=__next_month__&_r=' + Math.random()); return false;"></a>
</div>
```

is my given code.Need to apply these in the following buttons.

```
<div class="cal-head-right">
<button class="prev">prev</button>
<button class="head-day">Today</button>
<button class="next">next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: please make it clear.

Comment: More details about the problem needed.

Comment: Im not sure of how to use the above things using the html buttons below

Comment: Duplicate question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19833781/php-ajax-usage-in-html-button?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the buttons in the hyperlink.

```
<div class="cal-head-right">

 <a class="prev" href="index.php?month=__prev_month__" onclick="$('#calendar').load('index.php?month=__prev_month__&_r=' + Math.random()); return false;">
  <button class="prev">prev</button>
 </a>

 <button class="head-day">Today</button>

 <a class="next" href="index.php?month=__next_month__" onclick="$('#calendar').load('index.php?month=__next_month__&_r=' + Math.random()); return false;">
  <button class="next">next</button>
 </a>

</div>
```